# Jquery label value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to set the value of label using Jquery. I've tried .HTML(), .Val(), and .innerHTML but nothing seems to work. Any help would be appreciated.

JavaScript

```
$("#txtObjective").val(responseData[0].objective);
```

HTML

```
<label class="puma_Label" id="txtObjective"></label>
```

Comment: `.val()` is for inputs only., try `.text()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `textContent` (`.text()` in jQuery). Only input elements have a value property.

```
$("#txtObjective").text(responseData[0].objective);
```

Mandatory vanilla explanation:

```
document.getElementById("txtObjective").textContent = responseData[0].objective;
```

As for the `html` options -- those are simply bad practice to use here. Unless you're rendering HTML, never use `innerHTML` or `html()`.